# Converting dictionary values that are lists of strings to lists of integers

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with keys that are lists of strings (which are numbers), something like this:

```
 mydict = {'green': ['-1', '0'],
 'orange': ['-1', '0', '9'],
 'red': ['-1', '0'],
 'yellow': ['0'],
 'white': ['-1'],
 'black': ['-1'],
 'pink': ['-1']}
```

Now I'd like to convert the values to integers, such that:

```
mydict = {'green': [-1, 0],
     'orange': [-1, 0, 9],
     'red': [-1, 0],
     'yellow': [0],
     'white': [-1],
     'black': [-1],
     'pink': [-1]}
```

I've tried using list comprehension

```
mydict_int =dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in mydict.items())
```

but it throws an error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Comment: `new_dict = {key: [int(x) for x in val] for key, val in mydict.items()}`

Comment: typecast elements of v instead of whole v list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly convert lists to `int`, but you can individually convert their elements  with a list comprehension:

```
mydict_int = dict((k, [int(s) for s in v]) for k,v in mydict.items())
```

Comment: Or `{k: [...] for ...}` (but your way is closer to OP's original code, thus showing only the necessary changes)

Answer (score 1):

You have to not only iterate over dictionary keys (for which, incidentally, the "dict comprehension" syntax is easier to read),  but also over *each* value of the list of each dictionary value:

```
mydict_int = { k : [int(value) for value in sequence]   for k, sequence in mydict.items() }
```

The exception you are reporting comes from trying to pass the whole list itself in `int()` rather than each element.

Answer (score 1):

```
new = {}
for i in mydict:
    new[i] = [int(k) for k in mydict[i]]
```

this is how you can convert the strings into integers. but this code assumes that there won't be any non integer values in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can map `int` to each element in the list as well:

`{k: list(map(int, v)) for k, v in mydict.items()}`